# How to get the latest pdf document from a list of pdf documents which are in document library in sharepoint2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

When I click a button in home page it has to open the latest weekly buzz which is a pdf document and is located in document library.When ever they upload the new one it has to open up the new one. Could you suggest me how to do it.Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Which version of SharePoint?

Comment: HI Christophe,I am using sharepoint 2013

Comment: What is the meaning of the hierarchy in your diagram? A doc library cannot contain another doc library.

Comment: I am sorry, I made changes to the hierarchy.Sample doc library has nested folders.Using sharepoint designer I am able to get the folders Weeklybuzz,Test1,Test2 .But I have to get the latest weeks pdf from nested folders.

Comment: Using such a hierarchy is usually a very bad practice, inherited from file shares. In SharePoint you should not need such folders (especially labelled by date).

Comment: Somebody built the hierarchy.In different pages we are displaying different folders like Sample page/WeeklyBuzz/April2014Folder,Feb2014Folder..etc./ week1.pdf,week2.pdf..etc

Comment: yeah, that's ugly. Nothing you can do about it? The beauty of SharePoint is that it can create dynamic pages, you should never have to create one page per week like this.

Comment: We are not creating one page per week.We are adding a pdfdoc per week in Weeklybuzz folder-->May 2014folder---->week1.pdf

Comment: Yes, I understand. I'm just saying there's no reason to do that when you use SharePoint. Certainly a habit that dates back from when the team was using file shares?

Answer (score 2):

The simplest solution is to upload the document always with the same file name and overwrite the existing version.

If you need to retain a copy for each version, you may want to try the following.

Create a new document library called "DisplayDoc".

Create a workflow in the original document library that runs when a document is created.

The workflow will

- delete a document in the DisplayDoc library called TheFile.pdf
- copy the current document to DisplayDoc
- rename the document in DisplayDoc that has the same name as the current document and assign the file name TheFile.pdf

Now all you need to do is to seed a file called TheFile.pdf in the DisplayDoc library and let the workflow in the other library run whenever a file is created.

On the home page you can create a link to DisplayDoc/TheFile.pdf and that never needs to change.

Tested and working in SP 2010. Should work along the same lines in SP2013

Comment: Another way would be to just switch on version history for the document library. +1 for the simplicity of this approach.

Comment: Can the downvoter please add a comment?

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way is to create a filtered view that only displays the last uploaded document. In the view settings:

- sort by modified date, descending order
- limit the number of displayed items to one

Programmatically, you could use the REST services as you are on SP 2013, and proceed in two steps:

1. retrieve the ID of the last modified document
   `/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Documents')/items?$sort=Modified%20descending&$top=1&$select=ID`
2. retrieve the url of that document. For example if the ID from the first step is 42: `/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Documents')/items(42)/EncodedAbsUrl`

Answer (score 1):

You can use SharePoint Designer to drop the Document Library View on the page and limit the results to 1.

Than sort the results based on Modified date field (descending)

You can choose different layouts available in SharePoint Designer for showing the single item and play with XSLT to customize the view..

Reference:

[Change the number of records displayed in a Data View](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-designer-help/change-the-number-of-records-displayed-in-a-data-view-HA010237006.aspx)

Comment: Hi Arsalan,When I open the home page in sharepoint designer I am able to see in Dataview  Sample doc library only.But i have to get the Latest doc which is in Sample doc library/weeklybuzz doclibrary/Latest doc

Comment: Hi All,I included an image which describes the current hierarchy.They upload the doc every week.I have to get the current weeks doc in current month. In home page When they click the button it has to open the current weeks pdf doc automatically.